# Code coverage for node js on Apollo graphql using JEST (deployed server test)

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, graphql, code-coverage

I have a graphql server running on apollo framework (nodeJs) which has few tests written on both mock and deployed server scenarios i.e., running graphql queries/mutations on both mock server and AWS deployed servers. It uses JEST to run the commands and test. When I run the *--coverage* argument it gives the coverage report of the tests that were run rather than the coverage of the code on which its executed. Is it not possible to **get the code coverage in server to client scenario in nodeJs**?

Please let me know if I can do anything with JEST or if I can use any other plugin.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.